# Prove that $pTq \longleftrightarrow |p| = |q|$ is Equivalence Relation on $A$ set of all point in the plane

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that this relation is equivalence relation on A

1. $A$ set of all points in the plane
2. $pTq \longleftrightarrow |p| = |q|$ , |p| is the distance from origin.

about transitivity,  there are counter-examples?
for reflexivity is obvious, $(x,x)$ the distance will be the same.
for symmetry $(x,y)\in R , (y,x) \in R$ the distances are the same.
if its Equivalence Relation what are the equivalence classes? and partition set?

I would like to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexivity:

$$\forall\,(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\;,\;\;\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies (a,b)T(a,b)$$

Symmetry:

$$(a,b)T(c,d)\implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\implies\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies (c,d)T(a,b) $$

Transitivity:

$$(a,b)T(c,d)\;\wedge\;(c,d)T(x,y)\implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\implies$$

$$(a,b)T(x,y)$$

The equivalence classes here : $\;x^2+y^2=R^2 ...$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that this relation $T$ is defined by  *the equality relation* which's the most natural equivalence relation so $T$ will inherit the same properties and then it's also an equivalence relation.

**Remark** You can use this method for all relation defined by
$$xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$$

For the class equivalence of $x$:
$$[x]=\{y;\, xRy\}=\{y;\, |x|=|y|\}=C(O,|x|) $$
where $C(O,|x|)$ is the circle of center the origin of the plane and radius $|x|$.